# How iPhone tracks changes in contacts for syncing with Exchange?

Tags: iphone, ms-office, exchange

I have an iPhone SE that I sync with an Exchange server interface that is present on my home Wi-Fi network.  It does sync over the internet nor with a cloud.  The Exchange interface is presented to the iPhone by an AkrutoSync app running on my Windows laptop.  AkrutoSync is the intermediary that syncs the iPhone with Outlook desktop app on the laptop.

When I create a new contact on the iPhone, it sometimes doesn't show up on Outlook on the desktop, even when more recent edits to contacts on the iPhone *do* propagate to Outlook on the laptop.  When I *edit* the new contact that didn't get synced, it *does* propagate to Outlook on the laptop.

How does the iPhone determine what information to push to the Exchange interface?  It seems that *some* things are tracked and pushed, but not all such things.  Is it specified as part of the Exchange interface?